# EL1008E: Property or field ‘retry’ cannot be found on object of type ‘org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext’-maybe not public

Tags: java, spring-boot

Find stack trace in image

```
Caused by:

erg-springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ApilInvokerDelegate’: Unsat
dependency expressed through field 'excludedRetryStatus';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException. Expression
Parsing failed; nested exception is org-springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
ELIO08E: Property or field ‘retry’ Cannot be found
On Object of type ‘org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aizC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Before modification:

code added in Java file and this retry.excludeRetry added in application.properties file:

@Value(“#{retry.excludeRetry}”)
Private List excludeRetryStatus;

Post modification  :

So, this is Comma separated values in application.properties file

And we need to modify code like

@Value(“#{${retry.excludeRetry}.split (‘,’)}”)
Private List excludeRetryStatus;